# The correct way to get/close DataSource connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource

I am developing a dynamic web project on eclipse.

Below is an example of connecting MySQL using DataSource.
Is it the correct way? I mean is it normal to get connection in a Servlet?

Moreover, I find this way to get/close connection is tedious because I need to write exact same part of codes every time when I want to get/close connection. I think there should be a better way. Could someone give me some suggestions?

Thank you!

```
@WebServlet(name="HelloUser", urlPatterns={"/hellouser"})
public class HelloUserServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

            DataSource ds = MyDataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                con = ds.getConnection();
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(...);
                ...
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                    try {
                        if(rs != null) rs.close();
                        if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
                        if(con != null) con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: first learn about the `try-with-resources` construct, second consider learning about higher level JDBC libraries such as [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will try Spring JDBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Java 7 you can use `try-with-resource`( JDBC api is updated to implement Autocloseable) .

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it

E.g.

```
try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(...)) {...}
```